# Passing tables from C# code behind to a javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control that is part of an update panel. The user control is a heading( tag) and a asp Table. The asp:Table is defined in the ascx file only with the headers. The contents of this table are updated dynamically from the code behind by reading a csv file. This set up is within an Update panel which updates every minute. After every minute the csv file gets updated and hence the table needs to be updated.

Here is the tricky part. Before the table is I updated I need to save a copy of the old table and then update the new table. Once the new table is updated  and the page is about to be loaded I need to call a javascript function from in the page_load handler and pass the two tables. Inside the javascript function I need to compare the old table and the new table cell by cell and do some work based on the result of the comparison.

Here is how I copy the data from the table to another table before updating it.

```
TableCell tableCell;
TableRow tableRow;
for (int i = 0; i < Table1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    tableRow = new TableRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < Table1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    {
        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = Table1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    }
    oldTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
}
```

But for some reason when I pass the tables to the javascript function and access the cells in javascript I see only the headers and not any values in the old table. But when I access the cells in my code behind itself I can see the values.

My HTML is

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolderBody_ContentPlaceHolderBody_TradxPriceTable_5_oldTable" ClientID="oldTable">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">6M EURIBOR</td>
        <td colspan="3">6M EURIBOR</td>
    </tr><tr>
         <td>Instr</td>
         <td>Bid</td>
         <td>Ask</td>
         <td>Instr</td>
         <td>Bid</td>
         <td></td>
    </tr><tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td colspan="3">BASIS 3s6s</td>
    </tr><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Instr</td>
          <td>Bid</td>
          <td>Ask</td>
    </tr><tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My javascript is

```
function foo(table1,table2)
{
   var oldTable = document.getElementById(table1);
   var newTable = document.getElementById(table2);
   alert(oldTable.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML+" "+newTable.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: can you post a (snippet of) the generated html and the JavaScript pls

Comment: Is oldTable.Visible="false"?  If so, it would not be accessible by JavaScript on the client-side, but would be accessible on the server-side.

Comment: @CMKanode : Visible is not false.

Comment: @RuneFS: I am unable to figure out how to post html here. But what I see as generated HTML is a bunch of tr and td tags that are empty only the headers are intact.

Comment: how's your javascript called Ie what's the values passed for table1 and table2

Comment: I call it like this ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "OnChangeScript", "foo('" + oldTable.ClientID + "','" + Table1.ClientID + "');", true);

Comment: Whatever you see in the generated HTML is what is defined in the ascx file for the table Table1 and the rows and cols are populated dynamically. Similarly the copying of data to another table is also dynamically. When called from javascript using document.getElementById the old table has values only for those tds which have been defined in the ascx file for the table Table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use html tables and form a string with the tables and the values and pass that string to javascript.

```
string newTable = "<Table><Tr><Td>"+ somevalue +"</Td></Tr></Table>"
```

in javascript

```
var newT = '<%= newTable %>'
```

Comment: The javascript function is not in my code behind file. It is actually in a separate file. I am not sure if you can bind variables is that case? Also can we build a table in javascript by passing this HTML string?